# background and border wrap text according to longest line - CSS

Tags: html, css, border, background-color

I am trying to wrap a paragraph and UL with 4 lines in border and give it black background.

I want the border and background to wrap all the text according to the length of the longest line, I was able to do it for one line at a time but it means that there is no background color between the lines while I want the background and the border to wrap all the text together.

can't figure out how to do it.

This is the HTML code I have

```
<p><span class="commentBorder">
    some text about the next lines:
</span></p>
<ul>
    <li><span class="typesBorder1">first line text.</span></li>
    <li><span class="typesBorder2">second line text.</span></li>
    <li><span class="typesBorder3">third line text.</span></li>
    <li><span class="typesBorder4">fourth line text.</span></li>
</ul>
```

this is the CSS code I have:

```
.commentBorder{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.typesBorder1{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.typesBorder2{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.typesBorder3{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.typesBorder4{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like this?:

```css
.parent {
    width: fit-content;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<p><span class="commentBorder">
    some text about the next lines:
</span></p>
<ul>
    <li><span class="typesBorder1">first line text.</span></li>
    <li><span class="typesBorder2">second line text.</span></li>
    <li><span class="typesBorder3">third line text.</span></li>
    <li><span class="typesBorder4">fourth line text.</span></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, there is no "clean" way to achieve this, unless you add a parent layer that wraps the ensemble.

Note that I have added `width: fit-content` to it so that it adjusts to the widest element.

Comment: ok that did exactly what i wanted to do, but now all the text is on the left side, how do i get it back in the middle? i tried ```text-align: center;``` but it does not work, does it have to be with margin?

Comment: What do you mean by "all the text"? Only the p text or the ul li text as well?

Comment: both of them, they are centered inside the border, but the whole border is on the left side of the page

Comment: Then, just add `margin: 0 auto;` to the parent. I have updated my fiddle so that you can see the final result. ;)

Comment: yes, thats exactly what i was trying to do, thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
ul {
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 border: 1px solid black;
}
```

I think you want a background color on the whole ul, and you can remove the background color of each li

Comment: it works, but only for the ul, I want the paragraph in there too

Comment: then you need to put both the <P> and <ul> in a <div>. and give the div {
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 border: 1px solid black;
}